# htaccess RewriteRule redirect regex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect url requests from
`http://www.xyz.com.au/lid/cid_855_1404172`

To

`http://www.xyz.com.au/lid/1404172`

My regex matches the numbers after the last underscore but the final url is still appending the part I’m trying to omit

```
RewriteRule ([^_]+)$ /lid/$1
```

The result is:

`http://www.xyz.com.au/lid/cid_855_/lid/1404172`

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to match and replace parts, you need to match all parts of the URI not a partial match.

You may use this redirect rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?[^/]*_([^_]+)/?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

**Details of the regex used:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.+/)?`: Match 1+ of any char followed by a `/`in capture group #1
- `[^/]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `/` (longest possible match; greedy)
- `_`: Match a `_`
- `([^_]+)`: Match 1+ of any char that are not `_` in capture group #2
- `/?$`: Match optional `/` and end anchor